# Component not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a component that won't render it's sub-component. There's no errors in the console. I get the data I need from the web call, no errors with that. Not sure why the Project component isn't rendering anything.

Data Retrieval functions in separate file:

```
window.getCurrentUsersGroups = function() {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  var currentUsersBusinessArea = null;

  var userGroups = $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
    userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser()
  });

  userGroups.then(function(response) {
    var groups = [];

    $(response).find("Group").each(function() {
      var self = $(this);
      groups.push(self.attr("Name"))
    });

    currentUsersBusinessArea = _.filter(groups, function(group) {
      return _.startsWith(group, "BusinessArea")
    });
    d.resolve(getListings(currentUsersBusinessArea[0]))
  })
    return d.promise();
}

window.getListings = function(businessArea) {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  var projects = [];

  var listings = $().SPServices.SPGetListItemsJson({
    listName: "Projects",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='" + businessArea + "'/><Value Type='String'>Unassigned</Value></Eq></Where></Query>"
  });

  listings.then(function() {
    var result = this.data;

    result.map(function(project){
      projects.push({
        id: project.ID,
        pID: project.ProjectID,
        title: project.Title,
        status: project.Status,
        created: project.Created,
        businessArea: project.BusinessAreaFinanceAccounting,
        sponsor: project.SponsoringArea,
        comments: project.Comments
      })
    })
    d.resolve({businessArea: businessArea, projects: projects})
  })
  return d.promise();
}
```

Listing Component:

```
class Listings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      businessArea: null,
      projects: [],
    };
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let that = this;
    window.getCurrentUsersGroups().then(function(response) {
      response.then(function(data){
        that.setState({businessArea: data.businessArea})
        that.setState({projects: data.projects})
      })
    })
  };

  render() {
    let {businessArea, projects} = this.state;
    console.log(this.state)

    return (
      <section className="listingsContainer">
        <h3>{businessArea}</h3>

        <hr></hr>

        <table className="ms-Table">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Project ID</th>
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th>Response Status</th>
                <th>Initiated Date</th>
                <th>BA Impact</th>
                <th>Sponsor</th>
                <th>Comments</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {
              projects.map( function({project,index}) {
                console.log(project.ID)
                return <Project key={project.id} project={project} index={index} />
              })
            }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

Project Component:

```
const Project = ({project, index}) => {
  return (
    <tr key={index + project.ID}>
      <td>
        <a href={_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/SitePages/Business%20Project%20Edit.aspx?ProjectID=' + project.ID}>
          <span style="font-size:1em;" className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--editBox"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>{project.ProjectID}</td>
      <td>{project.Title}</td>
      <td>{project.Status}</td>
      <td>{project.Created}</td>
      <td>{project.BusinessAreaFinanceAccounting}</td>
      <td>{project.SponsoringArea}</td>
      <td>{project.Comments}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};
```

Browser Result:

If I output $r in the console, the Listing component state has projects in it. But the react dev tool says the array is 0 and nothing is rendering. Confused.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using jQuery with react? And this binding is invalid, `<td>project.ProjectID</td>` it need curly braces

Comment: What is `data.length` in `render()`?

Comment: You have missed curly braces inside the `<td>` which renders the project data. `<td>{project.ProjectID}</td>`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly you're right, I screwed up the data binding here. Thanks for pointing that out. But it's still not rendering.

Comment: @robertklep data.length shows 0 at first then it shows 3

Comment: @Batman okay that's good, it means that something _should_ be rendered. Can you see the `<tr>`'s appear in the DOM (use your browsers' dev tools to inspect the table)? Perhaps it's a CSS issue?

Comment: They don't appear in the dom at all right now. `tbody` is just empty.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you forgot to wrap your `project` with curly braces:

```
const Project = ({project}) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href={_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/SitePages/Business%20Project%20Edit.aspx?ProjectID=' + project}>
          <span style="font-size:1em;" className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--editBox"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>{project.ProjectID}</td>
      <td>{project.Title}</td>
      <td>{project.Status}</td>
      <td>{project.Created}</td>
      <td>{project.BusinessAreaFinanceAccounting}</td>
      <td>{project.SponsoringArea}</td>
      <td>{project.Comments}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};
```

Here's a nicer way to handle the Component's:

```
class Listings extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      businessArea: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let that = this;
    let groups = [];

    let userGroups = $().SPServices({
      operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
      userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser()
    });

    userGroups.then((response) => {

      $(response).find("Group").each(function() {
        let self = $(this);
        groups.push(self.attr("Name"))
      });

      let currentUsersBusinessArea = _.filter(groups, (group) => _.startsWith(group, "BusinessArea"));
      this.setState({businessArea: currentUsersBusinessArea})
    }).then(getListings)

    function getListings() {
      let listings = $().SPServices.SPGetListItemsJson({
        listName: "Projects",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='" + that.state.businessArea + "'/><Value Type='String'>Unassigned</Value></Eq></Where></Query>"
      });

      listings.then(function() {
        that.setState({data: this.data});
      })
    };
  }

  render() {
    let {data, businessArea} = this.state;
    return (
      <section className="listingsContainer">
        <h3>{`Business Area ${businessArea}`}</h3>
        <hr></hr>
        <table className="ms-Table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Edit</th>
              <th>Project ID</th>
              <th>Project Name</th>
              <th>Response Status</th>
              <th>Initiated Date</th>
              <th>BA Impact</th>
              <th>Sponsor</th>
              <th>Comments</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {data.map({project,index}) => <Project key={index} project={project} /> }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

const Project = ({project}) => (
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href={_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`/SitePages/Business%20Project%20Edit.aspx?ProjectID=${project}`}>
          <span style={{'fontSize':'1em'}} className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--editBox"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>{project.ProjectID}</td>
      <td>{project.Title}</td>
      <td>{project.Status}</td>
      <td>{project.Created}</td>
      <td>{project.BusinessAreaFinanceAccounting}</td>
      <td>{project.SponsoringArea}</td>
      <td>{project.Comments}</td>
    </tr>
);
```

Tip: Never Mix Jquery with React Components

Comment: I didn't know I couldn't use both together. I thought I was suppose to keep the data retrieval and all that in the component. I need jQuery to clean the data up. Where am I suppose to do that? Thanks for the tickets on decoupling and just putting the `data.map` in the `tbdody` I like that.

Comment: @Batman handle the incoming data outside the react component what do you use with react?

Comment: What do I use with React? Like which libraries? Also, are you saying all the code in `componentDidMount()` should be somewhere else?

Comment: @Batman I'm not really sure what you're building, I mix Redux with React. seems to be the best solution for me you can have that inside componentDidMount() but that's no "React Thinking"

Comment: I updated OP and added an image of my console. I'm really confused as to what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason it wasn't rendering is because of this table cell:

```
  <td>
    <a href={_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/SitePages/Business%20Project%20Edit.aspx?ProjectID=' + project.ID}>
      <span style="font-size:1em;" className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--editBox"></span>
    </a>
  </td>
```

The span tag as a `style` property. Which is preventing it from rendering from what I can see.